# How to bring the marker to middle of the screen?

Tags: vim

In vim, when I go to a marker, is there a way to tell vim to scroll it to the middle automatically instead of me doing `z.` or `zz` again?

or is there an event from vim when I go to marker like vim buffer events?

Commands to run pre and post inbuilt commands seems like a powerful thing. So there might be a plugin to do this. Couldn't find a query for google for this.

Comment: I would extend this question to include search commands.  I would love it if `n` would move to the next match and reposition the text.  Sometimes anyway, like if the match is in the lower or upper N lines of text.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `nnoremap <expr>n 'nzz'` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is just for moving to a marker with [`'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27) and friends (or just a few more select motions), you can override the original commands with custom mappings like this:

```
:nnoremap <expr> ' "'" . nr2char(getchar()) . 'zz'
:nnoremap <expr> ` "`" . nr2char(getchar()) . 'zz'
```

These basically turn (typed) `'a` into (executed) `'azz`; the complication here is that the `'` command waits for the typed mark; the mapping does this via `getchar()` before assembling and returning the full command. The `<expr>` makes Vim execute the right-hand side as an expression and use the result, instead of directly executing it.

---

To keep the cursor in the middle of the window at all times, set the [`'scrolloff'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scrolloff%27) option to a high value (like `999`) instead.

---

Speaking of *events*, there's [`CursorMoved`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorMoved) that is triggered after each move; unfortunately, there's no indication which command caused the move.

Comment: `scrolloff` is an option I've been wanting for a long time.  Thank you!

Comment: I have tried scrolloff, but it quickly became a problem for me, when i wanted to keep some code on the screen while i edit code near it. If possible can you explain the mappings you suggested. i don't have exp with <expr>. i ran them and tried to go to marker nothing happens, maybe am invoking them wrong.

Comment: My given mappings only work for `'` and ```. If you do `'a` for example, the cursor should move to mark `a` and center the line. I've also added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: One more doubt though. you only gave a single quote to the <expr> (on the lhs) why does that map to '<mark>, is it because there is no other mapping which starts with single quote.

Comment: That's the dynamism afforded by the `<expr>`; the second key (i.e. mark) is queried on the fly. The alternative would have been to explicitly define all mappings `'a`, `'b`, ... separately. So Vim already invokes the mapping after typing the `'`, but the mapping is only complete after another key has been pressed and incorporated into the right-hand side.